# How do you loop over the first 10 elements with a certain condition in XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an XML with let's say 100 elements `item`.
Now I want to make a loop over the first 10 items with a certain condition.

The conditional for loop could be like this:

`<xsl:for-each select="//z:item[@promoted='true' and @prio='true']">
  ...
</xsl:for-each>`

How do I process the first 10 elements only?

An easy solution would be this:

`<xsl:for-each select="//z:item[@promoted='true' and @prio='true']">
  <xsl:if test="position &lt; 11">
    ...
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>`

However this has the disadvantage, that the loop runs for all 10'000 items.
How can I make the for loop to include the condition "only the first 10" so that the loop really only goes over the first 10 items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first 10 that meet the condition:

```
//z:item[@promoted='true' and @prio='true'][11 > position()]
```

From the first 10 only those that meet the condition

```
//z:item[11 > position()][@promoted='true' and @prio='true']
```

Comment: Interesting difference. However the first one is the solution. Thanks!

Comment: Your wording might be interpreted either way. Thus the need for both answer in order to help future readers.

Answer (score 1):

You can make it part of your XPATH predicate, for example:

```
<xsl:for-each select="//z:item[@promoted='true' and @prio='true'][position() &lt; 11]">
```